# What does lexicografic Order of Consumers in Kafka exactly mean?

Tags: apache-kafka, partition, consumer

The question seems to be very easy, but I haven't found an explanation on it.
The default partition assignement strategy in kafka is with the RangeAssignor. How this assignor is working is explained as:

"The range assignor works on a per-topic basis. For each topic, we lay out the available partitions in numeric order and the consumers in **lexicographic order**. We then divide the number of partitions by the total number of consumers to determine the number of partitions to assign to each consumer. If it does not evenly divide, then the first few consumers will have one extra partition." https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/RangeAssignor.html

How it works is clear so far. Unclear is on what attribute the lexicographic order is done. Is done by the id of a Consumer?
Can anybody give an example for a lexicografic order of consumers?

Greetings,

maudeees

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since consumer client id is not required and group id should only be used for offset management, I assume it means by topic name, when the consumer is subscribed to multiple topics. If you are only using one topic, then only partitions are numerically ordered

Comment: Hey @OneCricketeer, thanks for your reply. If I got that correct, then RangeAssignor acts like Round Robin since a Consumer subscribed to only one topic?

Comment: Sounds logical to me.